# A non-numeric value encountered laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5.5

What is this error?

> A non-numeric value encountered (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\students\resources\views\layouts\header\header.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\students\resources\views\layouts\header\header.blade.php)

in my blade

```
<span clas="username">{{ auth()->user()->firstnames + ' ' + auth()->user()->lastname }}</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending string with the addition characters. When using the plus symbol php need numeric input.

You should just use the string concatenations symbol: the dot character:

```
<span clas="username">{{ auth()->user()->firstnames . ' ' . auth()->user()->lastname }}</span>
```